# Publish Single Worksheets in Excel Services Web Part on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is updated daily in a Document Library.  The spreadsheet contains 5 worksheets.

I want to create a number of Excel Services webparts that show only certain worksheets e.g.

webpart 1 to display only Worksheet 1 & 2
webpart 2 to display only Worksheet 1 & 3

and so on

I cannot seem to be able to define which worksheets to publish from the spreadsheet.  Searching in various documentation it suggests this should be possible.  Wondered if anyone can advise how/where this is configured?  I have tried entering worksheet names, Names Ranges, Cell ranges etc. in the Named Item field of the webpart properties but this gives an error to say the Named Item is not available.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in Excel 2010. Click on FILE > Save & Send > Save to SHAREPOINT > Publish Options. From the drop down, select SHEETS.
Uncheck the sheets that you don't want in the web part.

Hope this help.